# How to solution of linear-time varying system correctly

Tags: matlab, for-loop, ode45

I tried the given below to get the solution of the linear-time varying equation using for-loop, but the solution is not correct as I want to. I don’t know where I am getting wrong while implementing this.

```
r0 = 0.05;
L = 0.1;
d = 0.005;
w0 = 1.5;

Ts=10;
t=[0:Ts:800];
x0=[0 0 1]';
y0=1;
x_value=[];

for k=1:(length(t)) % Number of Iterations
x_value=[x_value x0];
g(k) =  (2*r0*L*sinh((d*(k))/2))./(d*cosh((d*(k))/2)+L*sinh((d*(k))/2));
    A0 = [ -0.5*g(k)   -w0    0 ; 
       w0     -g(k)*0.5   0 ; 
       0        0     -g(k)];
   B0 =[0; 0; -g(k)];
Q=integral(@(u) expm(A0*((k+1)*Ts)-u)*B0,(k*Ts),((k+1)*Ts), 'ArrayValued', true);
x0=expm(A0*Ts)*x0+Q;
end

plot(t,x_value,'r-','linewidth',1);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. As it stands, it's unclear what the problem is. How is your current solution incorrect, and how did you calculate the solution using `ode45()`? Please [edit] the question to clarify these points.

Comment: I have attached the ode45 result and system equations

Comment: Matlab's `ode45` uses adaptive grid and the precise algorithm is proprietary. How do you know `ode45`'s solution is correct? If you are debugging your code or validating your algorithm, it's best not involve a benchmark algo that uses adaptive grid since yours does not. Also it's best using something fully known.

Comment: Aside, your example code shouldnt execute. Please use viable (and minimal) examples on SO! The definition of `g(k)` isn't correct since `g(k)` is not a valid variable name. You can remove all of the `(k)`s or, since it is indeed better to define `g` as a standalone function, use `function out = g(k)...` block.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, for sake of better understanding I am not interested in ode45 results. My confusion is here that I want to solve the above discrete system using the numerical exponential matrix method. But the result I am getting is right, I am confused about where I am getting wrong.